# 2D array help on how to match and covert to string

Tags: java, class, methods, multidimensional-array

I have to write this class that will record a seating arrangement for a plane I am having trouble with 2 of my methods the methods say:

- `makeReservation(id, request)` — this method directly accesses seats to determine whether the seat is already taken. If not, record the id at that position in seats. Return true if you make the reservation and false if it is already taken,
- `getAssignment(id)` — search by rows and columns until you find a matching ID in seats, then convert the row and column into a string (e.g. `seats[5][2] == id` should return "6C".

How do I do this? 
This my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Plane {
private int[][] seats;
String flight;
String departure;

public Plane(String name, String leaving, int length, int width) {
    flight = name;
    departure = leaving;
    for (length = 0; length < 22; length++)
        for (width = 0; width < 5; width++)
            seats[length][width] = -1;
}

public String getFlight() {
    return flight;
}

public String getDepartureTime() {
    return departure;
}

public void setDepartureTime(String newTime) {
    this.departure = newTime;
}

public boolean makeReservation(int id, AvilaNatalyPassenger request) {
    boolean status = true;
    ArrayList<Integer> inputValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            id = seats[i][j];
            if (id != -1) {
                if (inputValues.contains(id)) {
                    status = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    inputValues.add(id);
                    // for(int x = 0; x < inputValues.size; x++)
                    // for(int y = 0; y < inputValues[x].size; y++)
                    // inputValues[x][y] = seats[x][y];

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}

public int getId(int row, int seat) {
    if (row >= 0 && row < seats[0].length && seat >= 0
            && seat < seats.length) {
        return seats[row][seat];
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

public String getAssignment(int id){
    for (



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare a static array with alphabet

```
private static String[] ALPHABET = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", ..., "Z"};

...

public String getAssignment(int id)
{

for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      if (seats[i][j] == -1) return new String((j+1) + ALPHABET[i]);

}
```

Comment: See what I'm supposed to return is numbers from 1-21 and a letter from A-D so it should return 12D, 4C... and this is how my class should look like:                                               Plane
- seats: int [][]
- flight: String
- departure: String
+ Plane(name: String, leaving: String, length: int, width: int)
+ getFlight(): String
+ getDepartureTime(): String
+ setDepartureTime(newTime: String)
+ makeReservation(id: int, request: Passenger): Boolean
+ getID(row: int, seat: int): int
+ getAssignment(id: int): String